# Parse whereKey: equalTo: not working

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

My query is supposed to search a parse class and return all PFObjects if they contain the string in the tags array. Without `whereKey: equalTo:` the code works and all objects show up but with it nothing shows.

```
import Foundation

class WallPost: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

@NSManaged var post: String
@NSManaged var user: PFUser
@NSManaged var tags: [String]

init(post: String, user: PFUser, tags: [String]) {
    super.init()

    self.post = post
    self.user = user
    self.tags = tags
}

override init() {
    super.init()
}



override class func query() -> PFQuery?{
    let query = PFQuery(className: parseClassName())
    query.includeKey("user")
    query.whereKey("tags", equalTo: "rock")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    return query
}

class func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "POST"
}

override class func initialize(){
    var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}
}
```

[this is what the parse class looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usxoJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be checking if an array on your Parse Server contains something, then it'd be best to use the containedIn predicate.
Like this:
`query.whereKey("tags", containedIn: ["rock"])`,
that'll give you all results that contain at least 1 instance of `"rock"`. You can think of `containedIn`as an `or` predicate, where only 1 of the items in the array have to match. Whereas `containsAllObjectsInArray` functions more like an `and`.

Comment: I still get nothing when I use `containedIn`.

Comment: replacing your equalTo with query.whereKey("tags", containedIn: ["rock"]) gives still gives you nothing? Weird. I'll keep looking.

Comment: yeah it's really weird. Thank you